# using jquery Show() with dynamic div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a div template like

```
var Mask="<div style='width: 60%;display:none; height: 602px;opacity: 0.3;' id='mask'>Hello i'm here</div>";
```

Now is tere any way to apply `.show()` jquery function to this div.

Comment: your question is quite unclear, may be this what you are looking for Container.append(mask). you have to append this to some container to visualize this div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
$("<div style='width: 60%; height: 602px;display:none; opacity: 0.3;' id='mask'>Hello i'm here</div>").appendTo("body");
$('#mask').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the div to the screen using document.write

```
document.write(Mask);
```

You do not need to use show() or on() because it will be shown when written to the screen

Comment: ya i'm able to but suppose if my div has display:none and if after document.write() i want to do a $('#mask').show() it shows error

Comment: I would do document.write(Mask); $('#mask').hide(); and then later on if you want to show it in some event handler or something, do $('#mask').show();

Comment: you didn't have jquery... now check it out.  You need to download  http://jquery.com/ and then include it before you can just use its functions

Comment: You need something like:

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

in the html of your page. (first download jquery.js file from jquery.com and change the src to be the path to where the file is relative to this page)  Or if you are using jsfiddle, you need to add it as a resource as I have done for you

Comment: Click on 'Add Resources' on the left and then paste this URL in the box: 

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: i dont know if i'm stretching it too long , but please check this..http://jsfiddle.net/s9C3n/  the $('#m1').Hide();​ is not working,ya its printing on the screen thnks to document.write....

Comment: use a lowercase 'h'. $('#m1').hide();

Comment: okkkk den i guess being new to jquery, i didn't knew jquery is case sensitive.Any waz thnks for pointing it out :)but i c a problem with this approach.All existing html is flushed from the page

Answer (score 0):

No, but fear not. You can append that string to the body HTML and it will render using the .appendTo() function.

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding this div dynamically use `$.on()` on
if this div was added in side the HTML (meaning not dynamically) use simple `$("#mask").show()`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show this div until you actually append it to the DOM. Once it is appended to an element it will automatically appear.

Please note that if you intend to append this div more then one time, you need to change `id='mask'` to `class='mask'`, as id must be unique.

Comment: i want to use this with all my pages so i dont want to explicitly use any container to appendTo, any way of achieving this